How do i use a value from a settings.json in a .ts file in angular?
i want to use debounceTime to let the user finish typing before suggestions are made. I want to make it customizable how much time the person is given before suggestions are made. To do that, i added a setting in my settings.json like this:
{
  "EN": {
    "workbaskets": {
      "time": {
        "debounceTime": 750
      },

I also exportet it as an interface in a settings.ts:
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';

export interface Customisation {
  [language: string]: CustomisationContent;
}

export interface CustomisationContent {
  workbaskets?: WorkbasketsCustomisation;
  classifications?: ClassificationsCustomisation;
  tasks?: TasksCustomisation;
}

export interface WorkbasketsCustomisation {
  information?: { owner: LookupField } & CustomFields;
  time?: DebounceTime;
  'access-items'?: AccessItemsCustomisation;
}

export interface DebounceTime {
  debounceTime: number;
}

Now I do not know how i can assign the value to debounceTime. I have tried the following in ngOnInit (i only include the relevant parts of code):
this.time = this.httpClient.get<DebounceTime>(customisationUrl).pipe(map((data) => {
      return data.debounceTime;
      })
    );

debounceTime(this.time)

I defined my variable as time: number = 0; outside of ngOnInit.
However, that throws the following error:Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Now i am a new beginner in Angular and therefore i still do mot know alot. I tried reading through already existing questions, however could not solve my problem and therfore I would be thankful for any help. Since the application already used the settings.json and settings.ts, i would like to continue using this for this setting as well and just need help with how to use the value as input to the function debounceTime.

From my understanding you do a request to "customisationUrl" and the response should be a "Customisation" instance. That means .... instead of this.httpClient.get you should have this.httpClient.get and now you have the entire structure and also the "debounceTime" value.

I have tried it, however it still gives the same error: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'number'. any idea how to solve that?

you should first subscribe to the method and then you can get the value of debounceTime.

 this.httpClient.get<DebounceTime>(customisationUrl).pipe(map((data) => {
  
  }).subscribe((response)=>{
       this.time = data.debounceTime;
 });

You cannot return the data from the map operator. you can only modify the data in the map operator. on the subscribe method you can assign the property to your local class property. In case of any other questions let me know.

Thank you for the answer. However, this.time is still undefined outside of this function. Do you know how to assign it to a global variable? I think it is because it is asyncronous and therefore it is excecuted last. Do you know how to force it to excecute first?

For force execution, you can use promise instead of observable. But you could try this in the constructor because the constructor is loaded early.
